# Stream not working on Firefox via QuickTime

Tags: firefox, quicktime

I have a live stream from 2 cameras. Code looks like this

```
<embed 
    id="QTlive" 
    src="empty.mov" 
    qtsrc="rtsp://IP:ADDRESS/live/video/ch1&amp;authbasic=LOGINPWD=" 
    width="800" 
    height="600" 
    scale="tofit" 
    autoplay="true" 
    loop="false" 
    controller="true" 
    wmode="transparent" 
    type="video/quicktime" 
    pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/" 
>
```

On server it's working perfect with Safari but on Firefox i got blank, white box. When i run local file .html via Firefox it's working but on remote server it's not.

I have QT installed on Firefox and using Mac.

Any ideas how to solve this problem ?